# SQLAlchemy to Load CSV to Database in Docker

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, docker, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use SQLAlchemy to copy data from one Database to another, all within a Docker container. Unfortunately, I don't know the schemas of the databases ahead of time, so I have to execute everything through `sqlalchemy.text`.

I have gotten to the point where I can pull data from the filled database, bring it into a Pandas DataFrame and filter it appropriately. The step I am stuck on is the final one; Writing it to a CSV and then copying it to the empty database.

What I am doing is saving the Pandas DataFrame to a CSV file, then attempting to run a `COPY` query using `sqlalchemy.text` to perform the copy. I generate the `COPY` query with the below:

```py
pushQuery = """
    COPY {table}({columns})
    FROM '{filePath}'
    DELIMITER ','
    CSV HEADER
    NULL 'NULL';
""".format(
    table=self.name,
    columns=self.columnStr,
    filePath=tempFilePath,
)
```

However, when I run the `COPY` query, I get one of two responses:

- If I have generated the CSV file in the docker containers `/opt/` folder, the response is that the file does not exist despite the fact that it is definitely there:

```py
(psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFile) could not open file "/opt/testing/testFile225.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.

[SQL: 
            COPY history_table(site_id, id, email_key, recipient_user, recipient_email, date_sent)
            FROM '/opt/testing/testFile225.csv'
            DELIMITER ','
            CSV HEADER
            NULL 'NULL';
        ]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

- If I have generated the CSV file in the docker containers `/root/` user folder, the response is that `psycopg` doesn't have the necessary permissions:

```py
(psycopg2.errors.InsufficientPrivilege) could not open file "/root/testFile833.csv" for reading: Permission denied
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.

[SQL: 
            COPY history_table(site_id, id, email_key, date_sent, recipient_email, recipient_user)
            FROM '/root/testFile833.csv'
            DELIMITER ','
            CSV HEADER
            NULL 'NULL';
        ]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Any ideas how I can resolve one or both of these errors?

Comment: The signal to noise ratio in your question makes it a bit hard to answer. Always try to trim things down to what is necessary.  

It looks like the only thing that you need to know is to do with docker files and permissions...

How do you know that the file definately exists?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the Dockerfile for the system in question; My solution needs to integrate with the existing architecture. I know the files exist because I can `exec ... bash` into the container and find it using `cd` and `ls`

Comment: But you say "If I have generated the CSV file in the docker containers /root/ user folder..." so you have control over where the file gets saved? How are you getting the file into the container?

Comment: Yeah, that is why I am confused; Python is able to write the file to the folder, but then can't read it. The file is generated in the container originally, as I am executing Python within the container

Comment: I have gotten it working by using `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql` rather than saving as a CSV and using SQL `COPY`, but it is slower than I would like on the bigger tables, so I would love insight as to how to get `COPY` working.